# Finding a regex pattern using JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I need a Regex expression for the following:

```
9845d530c7594ab45e8b905bbff
```

It should always start with 984, then have a UUID and the maximum length should be 27. Over here it is 5d530c7594ab45e8b905bbff (the UUID).I know for the UUID but I am not sure how to combine it in one. 
For starting with 984 it should be
 `^984`
And for a specific length it should be
 `\d{27}`
But I am not sure about UUID(which over here should be case insensitive).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  universally unique identifier (UUID) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Yes, but what is 27 UUID?

Comment: ^984[0-9a-f]{24}$

Comment: I edited the question @wik

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The UUID should be case insensitive

Comment: ^984[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Thanks so much also the UUID should be 27 in length (in max) but the present Regex you gave is 24 in length in max.

Comment: 24 plus the 3 static characters at the front = 27 characters.  And seriously, you should be able to adapt the pattern from here.

Comment: @Adrija 984 is 3 digits. 27 - 3 = 24. You said the "max" length should be 27, and it was vague whether you were talking about the entire string or just the part that follows 984. Especially confusing because the example string you provided is 984 followed by 24 digits, not 27.

Comment: Aren't UUIDs typically 32-digits (hex) e.g. {8}-{4}-{4}-{4}-{12}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^984[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$
```

A quick explanation:

- `^984` must begin with "984"
- `[...]{24}$` 24 characters that match the given character set, then end
- `[0-9a-fA-F]` a character set that includes any number 0-9, character a-f or character A-F

You can also use character classes `\d` for the numeric portion (must be a single numeric digit), but I like to be explicit, because otherwise my brain hurts.  Character classes are useful if you're running against an unknown character set that might have multiple representations for a number.  For instance, `\d` might match the Arabic numbers (٠‎ ١‎ ٢‎ ٣‎ ٤‎ ٥‎ ٦‎ ٧‎ ٨‎ ٩) or  Devanagari numbers (० १ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९).

There are also regex "modifiers" that allow case insensitivity without having to specify the upper and lower case in the character set.  It does depend on which regex implementation you use.

Java's [built-in regular expressions library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has a modifier flag:

```
Pattern.compile("^984[0-9a-f]$",CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```